# How to get network change (connect or disconnect) notification when app is in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessionconfiguration

In my application I need to capture the network connectivity status change while connecting or disconnecting even when my app is in the background.
I have implemented Reachability class.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
```

I am receiving the notifications successfully when app is in foreground. But when I keep the app in background and when there is any change in the network I did not receive any notification.

Could any suggest me on how to get this.

My actual requirement is I am using NSURLSessionConfiguration & DownloadTask which I need to cancel when there is a network connection lost even when the app in background.

So I wanted to get the network changed notification even in the background.

[I am using objective c and I need to support from iOS9]

can anyone please help me.
thanks

Comment: Did you check the ARC life-cycle of your Reachability class?, it may have been removed.

Comment: Reachability class it not sending notifications when app in the background.